# node.js - StripeConnectionError

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Recently receiving the following error when trying to look up either Stripe customers or accounts via Node.js.

I'm using `stripe.accounts.retrieve` and `stripe.subscriptions.retrieve`.

```
{
  "type": "StripeConnectionError",
  "stack": "Error: An error occurred with our connection to Stripe\n at Constructor._Error (/var/www/w3bbi/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:12:17)\n at Constructor (/var/www/w3bbi/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:124:13)\n at Constructor (/var/www/w3bbi/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:124:13)\n at ClientRequest. (/var/www/w3bbi/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:206:9)\n at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:7)\n at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:358:9)\n at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:7)\n at emitErrorNT (net.js:1280:8)\n at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)\n at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)",
  "message": "An error occurred with our connection to Stripe",
  "detail": {
    "code": "ECONNRESET"
  },
  "raw": {
    "message": "An error occurred with our connection to Stripe",
    "detail": {
      "code": "ECONNRESET"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea on what may be causing this? I just upgraded my OpenSSL package on my Ubuntu server but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

This error doesn't seem to occur every time, but only every few attempts. Most times I successfully retrieve the Stripe subscription or account, but every so often, I get this error instead.

Also my node.js code is very simple--

```
stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(STRIPE_SUB_ID, function(err, subscription) {
 //want to do something with subscription here, but i get err instead (only ever so often)
})
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `curl`ing the stripe API?

You can

1. Login into you stripe account
2. Go to https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#retrieve_customer
3. Copy paste the request from sample. it will some thing like `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_DbAXqdmjzVPz2I \    -u
   <your private api key>`
4. Paste your response here

Let me know if it is working,
Also can you share your node js code (omitting your key) if it is ok.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.

It says

```curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.stripe.com:443```


Also my node.js code is very simple--

```stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(STRIPE_SUB_ID, function(err, subscription) {

//want to do something with subscription here, but i get err instead

})```

Comment: According to error message, it seems that you SSL/TLS version is not supported by the API. 

According to this link
https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-openssl-to-support-tls-1-2

Can you try to run the following command 
```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade openssl

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libssl-dev
```
let me know if the above helps.

Comment: It seems upgrading the SSL/TLS did the trick! I am not 100% sure but have not seen any errors come up yet. I will continue to monitor the issue and update this thread if necessary.

Thank you so much!